# Angular directive selector can't apply icon to the element

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to do something similar to this application:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-sort-and-filter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This is my application :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-sort-and-filter-w9hrc3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

HTML:

```
<thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th
                *ngFor="let item of list.table.headings; let i = index"
                scope="col"
                sortable="{{ item.content }}"
                (sort)="onSort($event, i)"
              >
                {{ item.content }}
              </th>
            </tr>
</thead>
```

Directive:

```
export type SortColumn = string | '';
export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';

const rotate: { [key: string]: SortDirection } = {
  asc: 'desc',
  desc: '',
  '': 'asc',
};

export const compare = (
  v1: string | number | boolean | Date,
  v2: string | number | boolean | Date
) => (v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0);

export interface SortEvent {
  column: SortColumn;
  direction: SortDirection;
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()',
  },
})
export class SortableHeaderDirective {
  @Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';
  @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
  @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

  rotate() {
    this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
    this.sort.emit({ column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction });
  }
}
```

An up and a down icon is appearing when the user clicks on the header of the table in the original code (first link). But in my code, it didn't appear. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide code snippets in your question.

Comment: @WillAlexander , I added code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the rendered `<th>` element:

```
<th _ngcontent-hpt-c62="" scope="col" ng-reflect-sortable="Tercih"> Tercih </th>
```

There is no `sortable` attribute, while your `SortableHeaderDirective` is applied to `<th>` element with `sortable` attribute: `'th[sortable]'`.

With `sortable="{{ item.content }}"` or `[sortable]="item.content"` is used as property binding.

You can perform either of these to add the `sortable` attribute:

1. Add `sortable` without string interpolation.
2. Add `[attr.sortable]="item.content"`.

```
<th
  *ngFor="let item of list.table.headings; let i = index"
  scope="col"
  sortable="{{ item.content }}"
  (sort)="onSort($event, i)"
  sortable
>
  {{ item.content }}
</th>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-sort-and-filter-u94qqd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: do you know why this happens? if you add sortable without interpolation i.e. `sortable="test"` then it works. I am curious to know why the `sortable` attribute won't be added when using interpolation

Comment: I not 100% sure. I test based on what I see. `sortable="{{ item.content }}"` will be rendered as `ng-reflect-sortable="value"` which I believe this is used to pass the value as Input binding. Thus the `<th>` is missing `sortable` attribute. Either have to add  `[attr.sortable]="item.content"` or `sortable` (without string interpolation) will fix the issue.

Comment: rather [sortable]="item.content"

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I fixed issue and added it as an answer. But your solution is logical. It's interesting but it didnt work with th element , it worked with div element :S

Comment: No, you missunderstood me . I mean your solution works but i fixed issue by changing th to div. @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div
          *ngFor="let item of this.list.table.headings; let i = index"
          class="table-view__item__col {{ item.class }}"
        >
          <div scope="col" (sort)="onSort($event, i, this.table)" sortable="{{ item.content }}">
            {{ item.content }}
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'div[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.sorting]': 'true',
    '[class.sorting-desc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.sorting-asc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()',
  },
})
```